# Live Update the string content in console

Tags: c++

I just got into c++ and I'm having some problems doing the next thing:

I have the next "setup":

```
string curent = "None";

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome , etc";
    cout << "Current Mode: " << curent;
    while (true) {
       if (GetKeyState(VK_NUMPAD0)) 
       {
           string curent = "Mode 1";
       }
       // more modes
    }
}
```

How can I Have the

> Current Mode: None

cout automatically update based on the IF inside the main?( should become Mode 1 if NUMPAD 0 is pressed).

I would want to use something else than clearing all the console and re-writing everything , I only want the last line to update.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\b` to move caret to the previous symbol on the current line, then print new mode on top of the previous one.

Here's an example:

```
std::cout << "Mode: foo";
// Terminal shows
// Mode: foo
//          ^

std::cout << "\b\b\b";
// Terminal shows
// Mode: foo
//       ^

std::cout << "bar";
// Terminal shows
// Mode: bar
//          ^
```

Comment: What if there will be a Mode that will have 4 characters and another one that has 6 characters , how am I supposed to get the exact position, right after "Mode:" ? Also , is this a good practice for a infinite loop?Thank you

Comment: @an4rei There is nothing wrong with using it in an infinite loop. *"how am I supposed to get the exact position"* I would pad all mode names with spaces so that they all have the same length.